# IIS 10 Manager Showing only start page, Not showing site

Tags: iis, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I have add feature for IIS web server in windows server 2019. and installation successfully completed. but it show only start page and local connection. Default site is missing. How I recover it.

I have run IIS with both "Run As Administrator" and normally.

For reference I have attach the screen shot of my IIS.

[image]

Windows Server Role Configuration

[image]

Comment: Show us your Windows Server role configuration window.

Comment: I have added Windows Server role configuration in Post @Dai

Comment: I'm fairly certain (but not entirely) you now need to install the **Management Tools > Management Service** to use IIS Manager for a localhost IIS instance. You can keep remote connections disabled (they're disabled by default).

Comment: installed but same as before, is there any further process after install?  @Dai

Comment: No idea, sorry - do any of these QAs help? ( https://serverfault.com/questions/615514/iis-8-5-manager-application-pools-and-sites-nodes-missing https://serverfault.com/questions/410705/what-permissions-do-i-need-if-iis-manager-is-blank-or-empty )

Comment: Have you checked which username you have logged in with? Does the user have administrative privileges? Is that a local user or domain user?